# how do i draw in a canvas with consistent opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, opacity

I wanted to add opacity to the brushes in my paint program/app so I lowered the opacity via `ctx.globalAlpha` btw I'm drawing using paths. I got something like this:

snippet (no drawing functionality);

```js
//context
c = document.getElementById('c').getContext("2d");

//set opacity/alpha
c.globalAlpha = 0.5

//draw lines
c.beginPath();
c.lineWidth = 20;
c.lineCap = 'round';

c.moveTo(20,20);
c.lineTo(60,20);

c.stroke();
c.beginPath();

c.moveTo(60,20);
c.lineTo(70,50);

c.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
<style>
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

here is a [picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eb9P.png)

as you see it's not a solid transparent color you can see dark spots (not good). **so how do I fix 
that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transparency is consistent, but this spot you are applying it twice, so it accumulates. If you only have the problem in one path, you should repeatedly call moveTo/lineTo and only stroking at the end.

However i guess you want more than that. The solution is to draw on an off screen canvas. Initialise like this:

```
// your main canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create an offscreen canvas: this canvas is not shown on screen
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offscreenCanvas.width = canvas.width;
offscreenCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var oc = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

And then draw/update like this:

```
// you are drawing to the offscreen canvas
oc.beginPath();
oc.lineWidth = 20;
oc.lineCap = 'round';
oc.moveTo(20,20);
oc.lineTo(60,20);
oc.stroke();
oc.beginPath();
oc.moveTo(60,20);
oc.lineTo(70,50);
oc.stroke();

// and then copy the offscreen canvas onto your main canvas with opacity
c.globalAlpha = 0.5;
c.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0);
```

When you the user action is finished (e.g. after a stroke or what ever you require), you can clear the `oc` and start a new one.

This is also a recommended way for drawing many instances of the same graphics onto one canvas: draw once onto the offscreen canvas, then copy multiple times to your main.

UPDATE: since you are asking for "with drawing functionality", i created a working drawing example using another offscreen canvas to store state between user actions:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create an offscreen canvas: this canvas is not shown on screen
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offscreenCanvas.width = canvas.width;
offscreenCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var oc = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d");

// create another offscreen "freeze canvas"
var freezeCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
freezeCanvas.width = canvas.width;
freezeCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var fc = freezeCanvas.getContext("2d");

// for visualisation purposes you can also show these canvases
//canvas.parentNode.appendChild(offscreenCanvas);
//canvas.parentNode.appendChild(freezeCanvas);

var w = 10;

var le = null;
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  le = e;
  sw = w;

  // at the start of a stroke clear the offscreen canvas
  oc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (!le) return;
  
  // some primitive dynamic stroke width calculation
  var dx = e.offsetX - le.offsetX;
  var dy = e.offsetY - le.offsetY;
  var d = Math.max(1, Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy));
  sw = sw * 0.9 + (w * 4 / d) * 0.1;

  // add to your stroke image
  oc.beginPath();
  oc.lineWidth = sw;
  oc.lineCap = 'round';
  oc.moveTo(le.offsetX, le.offsetY);
  oc.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  oc.stroke();
  le = e;

  // and then combine the frozen contents with the stroke
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.globalAlpha = 1;
  c.drawImage(freezeCanvas, 0, 0);
  c.globalAlpha = 0.5;
  c.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  le = null;

  // and freeze the main canvas
  fc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  fc.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
<style>canvas { border: 1px solid black; }</style>
```

Comment: I don't really get it, I would like a full example **(with drawing functionality)**.

Comment: why does the brush get bigger and smaller?

Comment: as it is states in the comment this is "some primitive dynamic stroke width calculation" - it is based on speed: it gets smaller when drawing fast. it is just to show where you could add some dynamics to the stroke. @danGaming can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do not stroke after each move, here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-shadow-rql9q